# Animating annotationViews (loop animation), didSelectAnnotationView doesn't work

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, grand-central-dispatch, layer

So I am trying to animate my annotationViews using the following code :

```
   - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)annotationViews

{
    LLAnnotationView *aV;

    for (aV in annotationViews) {

        // Don't pin drop if annotation is user location
        if ([aV.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
            continue;
        }

        aV.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);
        aV.alpha = 0.1;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self animateAnnotationView:aV withAnnotationViews:annotationViews];
        });


       }
    }

-(void)animateAnnotationView:(LLAnnotationView*)aV withAnnotationViews:(NSArray*)annotationViews{

#define kDurationBetweenShowUpAnimations 0.4
#define kLoopAnimationDuration 1
#define kAnimationDuration 0.4

    // Initial animation

    [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration delay:kDurationBetweenShowUpAnimations*[annotationViews indexOfObject:aV]options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^(void){

        aV.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
        aV.alpha = 1.0;

    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration/2 animations:^(void){

            aV.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
            aV.alpha = 0.9;

        }completion:^(BOOL finished){

            [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^(void){

                aV.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
                aV.alpha = 1.0;
            }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                // **LOOP animation**

                [UIView animateWithDuration:kLoopAnimationDuration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^(void){

                    aV.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
                    aV.alpha = 0.9;
                }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                }];
            }];
        }];

    }];
}
```

Everything works as it should concerning the animation. 
But when I try to select an annotation View, didSelectAnnotationView is rarely called.

I suspect that this should be thread related.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution. Add UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction to the options of animateWithDuration :

[UIView animateWithDuration:kLoopAnimationDuration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction ...

!!